# Putting php foreach into single variable comma separated string

Tags: php, foreach

Hi this is probably really basic but cant do it for the life off me.

i have a foreach outputting values.

```
$tags = get_the_tags(); 

foreach($tags as $v) {

    echo $v;
}
```

this will output

```
php,css,cms,seo
```

i need to put all those into a single variable so i can do the following.

```
$keywords = "<meta name='keywords' content='".$tags."'>";
return $keywords;
```

can someone help i have tried

```
 $keywords = "<meta name='keywords' content='".foreach($tags as $v) {echo $v;}."'>";
    return $keywords;
```

obviously getting errors from this and its wrong how is it done???

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use implode():

```
$keywords = "<meta name='keywords' content='".implode(',', $tags)."'>";
```

You can also achieve the same result if you build a temporary variable using foreach:

```
$tmp = '';
foreach($tags as $v) {
    $tmp .= $v;
}

$keywords = "<meta name='keywords' content='".$tmp."'>";
```

Comment: how to get the comma separated from  foreach($tags as $v) {
    $tmp .= $v;
}

Answer (score 1):

you do not need foreach in this case [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) is what are you looking for

```
$tags=implode(',',$tags);

$keywords = "<meta name='keywords' content='".$tags."'>";
    return $keywords;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$tags=implode(',',$tags);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($order->line_items as $chinak){

     $promotion_value=array();
     $commission_value=array();
     $addition_value=array();
       foreach($chinak->commission_one as $key_pro_com_addition=>$pro_com_value ){


           $promotion=data_retrieve('promotion_setup', 'promotion_code', $key_pro_com_addition);
           $addition=data_retrieve('value_addition_setup', 'value_code', $key_pro_com_addition);
           $commission=data_retrieve('commission_setup', 'commission_code', $key_pro_com_addition);


           if($promotion['promotion_code']!=NULL){
               $promotion_value[]= $promotion['promotion_code'].'-'.$pro_com_value;
           }  elseif($addition['value_code']!=NULL){
               $addition_value[]= $addition['value_code'].'-'.$pro_com_value;
           }elseif($commission['commission_code']!=NULL){

               $commission_value[]=  $commission['commission_code'].'-'.$pro_com_value;

           }


     }

     $promotion_comma=implode(',',$promotion_value);
     $addition_comma=implode(',',$addition_value);
     $commission_comma=implode(',',$commission_value);
            $sql_com_prom="INSERT INTO ".TB_PREF."pro_com_value_addition(order_no,stock_id,value_addition,promotion,commission) VALUES(";$sql_com_prom.=$order_no.",".db_escape($chinak->stock_id).",".db_escape($addition_comma).",".db_escape($promotion_comma).",".db_escape($commission_comma).")";

              db_query($sql_com_prom);

   }
```